# Condition on the output to xterm of a variable that has been echo'ed in color

Tags: command-line, colors, xterm, tr

The fourth line of this code outputs the input argument in green color to an xterm.

However, I'd like to be able to condition on the value of the input.

If I input the word `Foo` then from bash's point of view, then the variable `word` contains not just `Foo` but rather `Foo` surrounded by characters related to coloring.  Hence the first conditional returns a failure.  I would have thought that the `tr` command below would strip off all of the color coding stuff and select only the word `Foo` but it fails to do so, and the second conditional returns a failure also.      Is there any way that I can filter out all but the contents of `$1`?

```
#!/bin/bash
Input=$1
word=`echo -en "\\e[38;5;41m$Input\\e[0m\\n"`  
echo $word
if [[ `echo $word` = Foo ]] ; then
    echo success
else
    echo failure
fi
word=$(tr -cd [:lower:]  <<< "$word")
if [[ `echo $word` = Foo ]] ; then
    echo success
else
    echo failure
fi
```

Comment: `[:lower:]` would only include visible alphabetical characters that are lowercase, so it would delete two o characters in Foo. The coloring control characters are technically are "non printable".  Also you don't need command substitution in `[[` ,just use variable directly

Comment: I don't think `tr` is going to be able to do what you wan anyway - [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output) is quite a bit more complicated than that

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver  If I create the perl script `uncolor` as per the thread you pointed to, then ,  `if [\`echo $word | uncolor\` = "Foo" ] ; then echo success ; fi` performs as expected.      Would you turn this into an answer so that I can accept it please?